# CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds, when trying to read Windows Server 2008

Tags: linux, networking, debian, windows-server-2008

When invoking the `check_nrpe` via terminal, like so:

```
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H winserver -c alias_cpu
```

I get the error below:

> CHECK_NRPE: Socket timeout after 10 seconds.

(Also via the Icinga web-interface)

According to the official Windows Monitoring documentations: [2.12. Monitoring Windows Machines](http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/monitoring-windows.html) when the above errors occurs, the following can be the cause:

- A firewall is blocking on the windows machine, on the Icinga server(Debian), or in between.
- The NSClient++ task is not running
- The port you specified is wrong

I checked the Windows Server 2008 firewall, and it does not block the specified port. And the Icinga server can - when using nrpe - check my Linux machines without a problem.

the NSClient++ is running, I verified that, by restarting the service by using the `stop` and `start` parameter.

The port is not wrong, I again verified, that by checking the `nsclient.ini`. the right port has been specified.

Here is how I set it up:

```
/etc/icinga/objects/winserver.cfg


define service{
        use                     generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name               winserver
        service_description     alias_cpu
        check_command           check_nrpe!nscp!alias_cpu
 }
```

I defined the command(s) from here:

```
/etc/icinga/commands.cfg


# 'alias_cpu' command definition
define command {
command_name alias_cpu
command_line /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H '$HOSTADDRESS$' -v '$ARG1$' -p 12489 -l '$ARG2$' -w '$ARG3$' -c '$ARG$'
}
```

If this is of help: In my `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` I specified under `server_address` the IP address of my winserver, and under `allowed_hosts` I have specified the IP address of my Icinga server.

**Question**: How can I monitor my Windows server 2008 using icinga and nrpe?

Comment: Anybody there? Anybody?

Comment: is the firewall not blocking the port or is the port really open? You can test this quite fast by completely disabling the firewall.